# how to fix Unread Messages not working in odoo 11?

Tags: filter, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-11, odoo-view

i want to know how Unread Messages work in odoo 11.

In v8 it give all unread messages when i apply New Mail Filter
but in v11 i am not getting same result when i apply Unread Messages filter.

```
<filter string="Unread Messages" name="message_needaction" domain="[('message_needaction','=',True)]"/>
```

Comment: Do you have this field 'message_needaction' in your Tree view?

Comment: yes this is happening in default odoo views in projects and quotations

Comment: What results is it giving and what are you expecting instead?

Comment: result is i am not getting task's which messages i haven't read yet
and expecting result when apply unread message filter it should give all that tasks which messages i haven't read yet.